# Python: Where to put logging.getLogger

Tags: python, logging

I tried to put getLogger in the module level. However, it has some disadvantages. Here is my example:

```
from logging.handlers import TimeRotatingFileHandler

log_monitor = logging.getLogger('monitorlog')
log_monitor.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_monitor.propagate = False
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('somedirectory/monitor.log',
                                    when='h',
                                    interval=1,
                                    backupCount=30)
monitor_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(monitor_format)
log_monitor.addHandler(handler)
```

The problem is, when some other module import this one, the above code will be executed. It is possible, at that time, the `somedirectory` does not even exist and the build will fail.

Actually, this logger will be used in a class, so I am thinking of putting `getLogger` into the class. However, I feel if people create multiple object of that class, that piece of code will be called multiple times. I guess this part of code is supposed only to be called once.

I am pretty new to python. Where do people usually put their `getLogger` and in this case, where should I put this piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you just need to make sure you do your logger set up after the directory is created.

If you want to import the above and only then create the file, one way to do it is to put your code in a function.

```
def monitor_log_setup():
    log_monitor = logging.getLogger('monitorlog')
    log_monitor.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_monitor.propagate = False
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('somedirectory/monitor.log',
                                       when='h',
                                       interval=1,
                                       backupCount=30)
    monitor_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(monitor_format)
    log_monitor.addHandler(handler)

    return log_monitor
```

It is now safe to import this module, you just have to make sure the function is called before you want to start logging (after creating the directory).

You can then use `logging.getLogger('monitorlog')` to return the same logger as defined in the function whenever you need it throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to mix up the "import" with "init", you expect the API caller after import the library or module, the log object is available, this behaviour will leads to confusing understanding. 
  I think the best practice is to provide an "init" method, the caller call "init" method, make the object available. 
    However, you could also provide an implicit init way in the file, or just create the log file if it doesn't exist.